# Jest + Enzyme: How to test an image src?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Logo component:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "assets/images/logo.png";

const Logo = () => {
  return <img style={{ width: 50 }} src={logo} alt="logo" />;
};

export default Logo;
```

Test file:

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from "components/shared/Logo";

describe("<Logo />", () => {
  it("renders an image", () => {
    const logo = shallow(<Logo />);

    expect(logo.find("img").prop("src")).toEqual("blahh");
  });
});
```

But when I run the test, there is some weird error:

```
$ NODE_PATH=src jest
 FAIL  src/tests/Logo.test.js
  ● <Logo /> › renders an image

    TypeError: val.entries is not a function

      at printImmutableEntries (node_modules/expect/node_modules/pretty-format/build/plugins/immutable.js:44:5)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.serialize (node_modules/expect/node_modules/pretty-format/build/plugins/immutable.js:178:12)
```

How am I supposed to test that the image src === "assets/images/logo.png"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suppose that you write your tests inside a `__test__` directory near Logo components .

Anyway, import your "assets/images/logo.png" relatively to your test file.

if your project structure is like this

```
Project
├── assets 
│   └── images
├       |
│       └── logo.png
├── src 
│   └── components
├       |── Logo.js 
│       └── __tests__
├           └── logo.test.js 
└
```

First, Like I said import image into your logo.test.js by typing:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

import Logo from "./../Logo"; 
import logoImage from "./../../../assets/images/logo.png;

describe("<Logo />", () => {
    it("renders an image", () => {
        const logo = shallow(<Logo />);
        
        expect(logo.find("img").prop("src")).toEqual(logoImage);

     });
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

Upd 2023. As @tomhughes pointed out, Jest 28 has different logic in mocking transformations: https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28#transformer

For some reason this information is not clearly highlighted.
In ['Integration with wepack'](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack.html#mocking-css-modules) section it's displayed how to auto mock static assets with `transform`:

> If moduleNameMapper cannot fulfill your requirements, you can use Jest's transform config option to specify how assets are transformed. For example, a transformer that returns the basename of a file (such that require('logo.jpg'); returns 'logo') can be written as:

**package.json**

```
{
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
    }
  }
}
```

**fileTransformer.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';';
  },
};
```

So this would make your `wrapper.props().src` to be just a string(available for any kind matchers like `.toEqual`). Also it means `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()` also works like a charm respecting image path.

[upd] don't miss specifying `"babel-jest"` transformation for JS/JSX files in config

Comment: This works in Jest <= 27, if you're using 28 or higher (released April 2022) then you need to return an object, as documented here: https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28#transformer

Answer (score 2):

```
/* **Image component** */
import React from "react";
import PropsTypes from "prop-types";
/** Image Component - This is shared component, You can use this component for rendering images
 * @param (string) altName
 * @param (string) fileName
 * @Return element
 */
const Image = props => {
  const { fileName, altName } = props;
  return <img src={`/images/${fileName}`} alt={altName}></img>;
};
/* Apply validation on Text Component */
Image.propTypes = {
  fileName: PropsTypes.string.isRequired,
  altName: PropsTypes.string.isRequired
};
Image.defaultProps = {
  fileName: "dummy.png",
  altName: "dummy"
};
export default Image;

/* Image.test.js */
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Image from "./Image";

describe("Testing of Image component", () => {
  it("render image component with default value", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Image />);
    expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find("img").length).toEqual(1);
  });
  it("render image component with props ", () => {
    const props = {
      fileName: "facebook.png",
      altName: "facebook"
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Image {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find("img").length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from "components/shared/Logo";

describe("<Logo />", () => {
  it("renders an image with src correctly", () => {
    const wrapper= shallow(<Logo src="yourlogo.png" />);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual('<img src="yourlogo.png"/>'); // implement your ".toEqual(...)" to your Logo component result 
  });
});
```

Or, to access your src prop:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Logo src="blah..."/>);
expect(wrapper.find({ prop: 'src' })).to.have.length(1); // or any other check you need
```

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me...**

Component:

```
function Header() {
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="no logo found"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Test:

```
it('should set logo image src correctly', () => {
        const logoImg = mountedHeader.find('img')
        expect(logoImg.getElement(0).props.src).toEqual("images/logo.png")
    });
```

https://acloud.guru/forums/serverless-portfolio-with-react/discussion/-KxEN_3qG3G9oxSHjyAN/Testing%20React%20-%20Testing%20images%20using%20expect(image.node.props.src)

Answer (score 0):

```
describe("CharacterInfo", () => {
  const data={
    image:"ricky.jpg",
  }  
  it("should renders img src", () => {
     const wrapper=shallow(<CharacterInfo image={data.image}/>);
   });
  const imgSrc= wrapper.find("img").prop('src');
  expect(imgSrc).toBe("ricky.jpg");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To work around this error, you can add the mock in the test file where the error appears or in the moks configuration file that is being used by all test files

```
 jest.mock('next/image', () => {                                                                           
                                       
    return ({ src, alt }) => {                       
                                       
        return <img src={src} alt={alt} />;                                    
    };                                                         
 });
```