# Test logo component in React Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've a requirement same as 
[Jest + Enzyme: How to test an image src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232895/jest-enzyme-how-to-test-an-image-src)

where I want to test Logo component that only consist image 'logo.png'. I've tried the solution answered by [thierno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8074342/thierno).

### Logo component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
export default function LogoJCpenney1({ logopath, logowidth }) {         
    return (
        <img src={logopath} alt="logo" width={logowidth} className="logoOriginal"/>
    );
}
LogoJCpenney1.propTypes = { 
    /** original logo path of JCPenney */
    logowidth: PropTypes.string
};
LogoJCpenney1.defaultProps = {  
    className:"logoOriginal"    
};
```

### Test component

```
import React from 'react';
import {configure, shallow} from 'enzyme';
import LogoJCpenney1 from '../LogoJCpenney1/LogoJCpenney1';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({adapter:new Adapter()});

import logoImage from "./../../containers/assets/img/jcpenneylogo1.png";
describe("<LogoJCpenney1 />", () => {
    it("renders an image", () => {
        const logo = shallow(<LogoJCpenney1 logoImage={logoImage} logowidth="50" />);
        expect(logo.find("img").prop("src")).toEqual(logoImage);
    });
});
```

### Test result

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: logoPath instead of logoImage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending a `logoImage` prop to your `LogoJCpenney1` component, but what the component *actually* wants is a `logopath` prop (which it will use as the image's `src`). You shouldn't use the path to `import` in the actual logo image. You should just pass in the path as the `logopath` prop.

The reason you are getting `Expected string but received undefined` is because `logo.find("img").prop("src")` is, in fact, `undefined`... since you did not provide a `logopath` prop to your component.

Perhaps something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import LogoJCpenney1 from '../LogoJCpenney1/LogoJCpenney1';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const logopath = "../../containers/assets/img/jcpenneylogo1.png";

describe("<LogoJCpenney1 />", () => {
  it("renders an image", () => {
    const logo = shallow(<LogoJCpenney1 logopath={logopath} logowidth="50" />);
    expect(logo.find("img").prop("src")).toEqual(logopath);
  });
});
```

---

Based on the other StackOverflow post you referenced, you might be thinking, "But I don't just want to test that `src` is set correctly. I want to test that the `img` actually shows the `jcpenneylogo1.png` file."

I would advise against this. You don't need to test that an `<img>` properly displays an image file when given a `src`. That's third-party stuff that React and your browser have already taken care of, and it's not your job to test those things.

Since you're unit testing `LogoJCpenney1`, you just need to make sure that, when you pass `LogoJCpenney1` a prop called `logopath`, then it renders an `img` that has a `src` equal to that `logopath`.

Comment: As you lastly said, 'Since you're unit testing LogoJCpenney1, you just need to make sure that, when you pass LogoJCpenney1 a prop called logopath, then it renders an img that has a src equal to that logopath.' Can you show how to do this, I'm new to it. Thanks

Comment: @KishoreChowdhury All you need to worry about in your test is the last line: `expect(logo.find("img").prop("src")).toEqual(logopath);` If this passes, then that means you have successfully coded `LogoJCpenney1` to include an `img` tag with a correct `src` prop. You do not need to test that `img` actually renders an image. My code example above demonstrates the test that you need.