# Is it possible to override jest configuration defined in node_modules library from project configuration?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

We are using some custom client library (added as dev dependencies in our package.json) which has all configurations related to jest and react JS. However, we are facing some issues while executing the test cases in which its failing because of images import in the source code. On further investigation, we saw that we need to mock the image import as a jest by default does not understand image import. 
To mock the image import we need to add transform in package.json and add some script like below link:
[Jest + Enzyme: How to test an image src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232895/jest-enzyme-how-to-test-an-image-src)

However, this config is not present in the library and we cannot edit package.json of libraries.

Is there any way to override that jest configuration in the project itself?

Comment: Jest configuration should be added in your project's package.json file. Why do you want or need to modify some third party's library package.json file?

Comment: its not a third party library, its client custom library. Client wants to use that library to be use as wrapper and use everything from it. Now this library does not have transform configuration for image import mocking. So, just want to check is there any possibility to override or add the jest configuration to given library. 
If not then probable we need to ask client to update their library to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably override it within your apps jest.config.js

```
const getJestConfig = require('')

module.exports = {
  ...getJestConfig(),
  // do your bits
  }
}
```