# Jest+React Testing Library+Enzyme: How to test an image src?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I am trying to test an image src on an existing code using React Testing Library, Enzyme and Jest. I have already found that some changes have to be done to the jest.config.js file according to this documentation:
[Jest + Enzyme: How to test an image src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232895/jest-enzyme-how-to-test-an-image-src),
https://jestjs.io/docs/next/code-transformation#transforming-images-to-their-path,
https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack
and as suggested by @skyboyer

However, the test is still failing. Perhaps are there steps that I am missing or anything else that I have to add to some config file?

package.json

```
{
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
    }
  }
}
```

fileTransformer.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';';
  },
};
```

Component to test

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../images/logo.png";

const NavigationHeader = () => {
  return (
    <header className={cx(style.container, className)} style={{ height: 50 }}>
        <NavLink to="/" className="h-100">
            {/*  <img className={style.image} src="ciao.jpg" data-testid="img2" /> */}
            <img className={style.image} src={logo} />
        </NavLink>
    </header>
)
};

export default NavigationHeader;
```

the test

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { PureNavigationHeader } from ".";
import { ViewerType } from "../../../services/auth";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";

test.only("testing the image with imported img", () => {
    render(
        <StaticRouter>
            <NavigationHeader />
        </StaticRouter>,
    );
    
    const img = document.querySelector("img") as HTMLImageElement;
    expect(img.src).toContain("logo.png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
expect(img.getAttribute('src')).toEqual('logo.png');
// or
expect(img).toHaveAttribute('src', 'logo.png')
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute
- https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute

Comment: Actually the problem is not selecting the img element but that the img src is not loaded in the rendered app. I have already tried what you suggested but the src results in an empty string

Comment: Oh right. I'm using create-react-app, without the Jest transformer, and img elements + src attributes are correct in DOM. I suppose you have a different webpack setup.

Comment: yes, this is a third party repo and uses webpack. I should have added the requested transformations but I cannot read the src when the img is imported from a path in the project